# Python getting element value for specific element

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am attempting to parse the below XML file but having difficulty getting a specific element value. I am trying to specify element 'Item_No_2' to get the related value `<v>2222222222</v>` but am unable to do it using get.element('Item_No_2'). Am I using the get.element value incorrectly?

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Data.xsl"?>
<abc>
  <md>
    <mi>
      <datetime>20160822020003</datetime>
      <period>3600</period>
      <it>Item_No_1</it>
      <it>Item_No_2</it>
      <it>Item_No_3</it>
      <it>Item_No_4</it>
      <it>Item_No_5</it>
      <it>Item_No_6</it>
      <it>Item_No_7</it>
      <ovalue>
        <v>1111111111</v>
        <v>2222222222</v>
        <v>3333333333</v>
        <v>4444444444</v>
        <v>5555555555</v>
        <v>6666666666</v>
        <v>7777777777</v>
      </ovalue>
    </mi>
  </md>
</abc>
```

My Code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

doc = parse('test.xml').getroot()

for element in doc.findall('md/mi/'):
    print(element.text)

for element in doc.findall('md/mi/ovalue/'):
    print(element.text)
```

The current output gets them separately but I can't seem to understand how to call a specific element value.

Output:

```
20160822020003
3600
Item_No_1
Item_No_2
Item_No_3
Item_No_4
Item_No_5
Item_No_6
Item_No_7


1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
4444444444
5555555555
6666666666
7777777777
```

Tried this but did not work:

```
for element in doc.findall('md/mi/ovalue/'):
    print(element.get('Item_No_1'))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Item_No_1` at the elements that are found by `doc.findall('md/mi/ovalue/')`.

I think what you may try to do is get both lists

```
items = [e.text for e in doc.findall('md/mi/it')]
values = [e.text for e in doc.findall('md/mi/ovalue/v')]
```

Then find the index of the string `'Item_No_1'` from `items`, and then index into `values` with that number.

Alternatively, `zip` the two lists together and check when you find one element.

```
for item,value in zip(doc.findall('md/mi/it'), doc.findall('md/mi/ovalue/v')):
    if item.text == 'Item_No_1':
        print(value.text)
```

There might be a better way, but those are the first ways that come to mind

Comment: Thanks for the response. The second alternative with ZIP gives me the wrong output. Provides 3333333 instead of 111111, do you know why?  I like the 1st option but can you tell me how I would get the index?

Comment: use `for item, value in zip(doc.findall('md/mi/it'), doc.findall('md/mi/ovalue/v')):`

Comment: @FujiApple Thanks, that did the trick to get the output matching the Item. Now I just need to play around some more and figure out how I can consistently get the right match in a larger xml with multiple elements that dont have a variable number of values. Cheers.